# $_POST values are not getting checked by my function

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is my first PHP project so please guide how to debug effectively :

**I created this form:**

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
<div class="fname">
  <label for="name"><span> Name: </span>
  <input name="name" value= "<?php 
  if($error_count != 0) {
  echo $name;
  }// To avoid filling name again in case of error?>"
  type="text" cols="20" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="femail">
  <label for="email"><span> Email: </span>
  <input name="email" value= "<?php 
  if($error_count != 0) {
  echo $email;
  }// To avoid filling email again in case of error?>" 
  type="text" cols="20" />
  </label>
</div>
<br/>
<textarea name="post" rows="5" cols="40"><?php 
  if($error_count != 0) {
  echo $post;
  }// To avoid filling textarea again in case of error?>
  </textarea>
<input name="send" type="hidden" />
<p>
  <input type="submit" value="shout" />
</p>
```

**and following function to validate form (in a seperate file form_validation.php):**

```
    <?php
function validate_shout($vmail,$vname,$vpost)
{

$error_count = 0; 

// To check email.
if(!preg_match('/^[.\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/',$vmail)) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> Please enter valid email address </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

// To check required fields
if($vname == NULL) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> Oops!! You forgot to enter your name </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

if($vpost == NULL) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> I guess your shout was blank </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

return $error_count;
}

?>
```

**And used it in this way**

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['post'])) {
echo "<p class=\"error\">Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</p>";
}
else {
 $name = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])); 
 $email = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])); 
 $post = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']));


$error_count = validate_shout($email,$name,$post);
//PHP code to add shout to database
if ($error_count == 0) 
{
$query = "INSERT INTO shouts SET name='$name', email='$email', post='$post';";
```

- Now the problem is that it is **not validating the textarea**. other
  two are working fine. Code was working fine few days ago. but today
  when i opened it i found this problem.

**One more thing i noticed was in phpMyadmin, as listed below**

*The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated. To find out why click here.*

on click it displayed this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Designer: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
Tracking: Disabled
```

I guess both the problems appeared together without any change in any settings or code by me. Although they look separate from each other.

Please help..

**Main problem is why $post is not getting validated and why phpMyadmin is suddenly showing the above mentioned message**

Comment: "Unable to connect to the database server at this time." <-- That error does not reflect the actual problem...

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks, ignore it...as it is not the problem. I will correct the error message.

Comment: If it were the problem, I'd have posted that as an answer :P

Comment: Elaborate on what "it is not validating the textarea" means. Does the error message appear always, or never? What was expected. -- Also if the last text block is irrelevant to the main question, remove it. (Only one problem per question.)

Comment: @cyclone: sorry i m new here.

Comment: @mario: it means that the textarea in the form is not getting validated by the function. i.e. even if it is null it is not showing any error to user instead the form gets posted to database. Error message doesn't appear at all. Last text block is here because i noticed both problems together so just wanted to know if there is any connection as i am very new to PHP so no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `== NULL` comparison will fail. Normally an empty string can also "equal" NULL. (You should preferrably write `== ""` anyway). But your textarea is unlikely to contain an really empty string. Just from your template I would assume it contains at least an newline, or a few more spaces even.

In that case you don't want to campare it against the empty string, but probe that it contains anything but spaces. To do so:

```
if (strlen(trim($vpost))) {
```

Anyway, to probe if a string contains anything, prefer `strlen()`. The `trim()` here is for filtering out whitespace prior to checking that.

#### Some other notes about your code:

- `htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string(` is the wrong order. The escape function is for the database. It must be applied **immediately** before concating it into SQL. Applying another encoding (html) afterwards might undo the SQL escaping.
- `<form action="<?php $self ?>"` won't work without some `echo`
- And the email regex is just braindamaged. Use `filter_var` and the builtin `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` regex

Comment: i tried it as you said. Well that's certainly a good suggestion but it is not working here. I tried HTML5 attribute "required" too but that is also not working for textarea but working for name.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. This worked for me: `if(!filter_var($vmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> Please enter valid email address </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

// To check required fields
if(!strlen(trim($vname))) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> Oops!! You forgot to enter your name </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

if (!strlen(trim($vpost))) {
echo "<p class =\"error\"> I guess your shout was blank </p><br/>";
$error_count++;
}

return $error_count;
}`

Comment: Also i was using this at the top of the page `$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` will NEVER return a `null` value, even if you pass in a `null` as an argument. It will at least return an empty string. Your validation function is checking for nulls, but because you're passing those values through M_R_E_S(), they can NEVER be null, hence your validation function is the cause of the trouble.

Comment: I replaced my function call with `$error_count = validate_shout($_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['post']);` but it is still not working.